# Select X using where clause and Y not using where clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to do a query like:

```
Select 5 from pictures where likes < 5 && select 4 from pictures
```

Basically, have a where clause on the first 5 pictures, and get 4 more pictures (but making sure that these other 4 pictures are not the same as those first 5 pictures)..

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM `pictures` WHERE `likes` < 5 GROUP BY id desc limit 0,5;
```

This is the result that I hope to get:

```
Picture 1 (Using where clause)
Picture 2 (Using where clause)
Picture 3 (Using where clause)
Picture 4 (Using where clause)
Picture 5 (Using where clause)
Picture 6 (Randomly selected from pictures, but making sure that this isn't a duplicate)
Picture 7 (Randomly selected from pictures, but making sure that this isn't a duplicate)
Picture 8 (Randomly selected from pictures, but making sure that this isn't a duplicate)
Picture 9 (Randomly selected from pictures, but making sure that this isn't a duplicate)
```

Basically, whenever I query it, I want all rows to be unique.

Comment: you could add the id's of each image selected to an array, then add an additional "where not exists in array" clause

Comment: @Takarii So weird that you said that.. I was just thinking the same thing... Would this be the best thing?

Comment: Not sure about "best", but its one way of doing it. I'd have a look at the answer below first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use union for this:

```
SELECT * FROM `pictures` WHERE `likes` < 5 group by id order by id desc limit 0,5
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `pictures`
WHERE id not in(SELECT id FROM `pictures` WHERE `likes` < 5 group by id order by id desc limit 0,5)
limit 0,4)
```

That way you select 5 pictures with a where clause, and another 4 without a where(only filters those who already been selected)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Select * from pictures where likes < 5 limit 0,5

union all

Select * from pictures where likes >= 5 order by rand() limit 0,4
```

Comment: He want the second query to be without a where clause

Comment: @sagi Where does he say this in the post?

Comment: On the title @giorgosbetsos , and you can figure it out by his first example, and by his output(no filter on it)

Comment: @sagi And how can we select anything at all without a `WHERE`?

Comment: Both very good answers, @sagi & Giorgos. But I think that I'm going to go with a "where not exist in array" solution.. Seems like the way to go in order to be 100% sure of no duplicates

Comment: Select * from table ? .. I didn't meant without a where, I meant without filtering.. look at my answer.

Comment: @sagi `NOT IN` is just another way of filtering ... never mind

Comment: I know, but its only to filter duplicates, not other pictures.. in your answer, the second query will never select pictures with likes <5

Comment: Both very good answers.. I'm going to have to go with @sagi answer though because what was mentioned above (in your answer, the second query will never select pictures with likes <5)